# Qt - Add files to project

Tags: qt

I'm making an application part of which is reading from an XML which stores some preferences. However, whenever I build the project, all the sources get copied but the preferences file does not! I have added the following to the .pro file - 
`RESOURCES += rsc.qrc`

And my rsc.qrc contains

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
    <file>data/preferences.xml</file>
    <file>data/gamedata.xml</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Now whenever I try to open preferences.xml

```
QFile preferences(":/data/preferences.xml");
if(!preferences.exists()){
    preferences.open(QFile::WriteOnly);
    preferences.write("abc");
    qDebug() << "Written";
}
else {
    qDebug() << "File exists";
}
```

Absolutely nothing gets printed and even the rest of the application stops working.

Comment: Could you please clarify where are your source files copied when you build the project?

Comment: @demonplus I have made a few changes to the code I put up. Let me know if there's something I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Are files actually in the data folder (does the folder exist)? Can you debug the application?

Comment: @demonplus I actually wanted to know this... In case the files specified in the qrc file do not exist, can you just simply write them like other files? Because I was trying to do that (write default preferences if file does not exist).

Comment: Actually no because resources are part of executable

Comment: look at QSettings, I think this is what you need

Comment: @demonplus I shall have a look at it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the resource part correctly in your example.
It will most likely not work because you try to write to a resource that is embedded into your executable after you have build your application. Reading is fine, but writing can't work by definition.

If you want a editable setting files, you have to distribute them along with your executable, or use a different method for reading/writing your settings like QSettings.

However using QSettings also means, that you will need to configure all your default settings in your loading function in case the values do not exist if you use the default configuration. Meaning you use registry on windows.

You have the option to force the use of a INI file format in the constructor of QSettings, this can make sense if you want to provide a default settings INI file instead of your xml files.

In case you want to store more complex data a xml file might be needed anyway, so if you want to stick with that you will need a way to copy your setting files to your build path. This can be done within your pro file with QMAKE_POST_LINK.

Example:

```
COPY_CMD = "$$PWD\\data\\preferences.xml $$OUT_PWD\\release\\data\\preferences.xml"
COPY_CMD = $${QMAKE_COPY} $$replace( COPY_CMD, "/", "\\" ) $$escape_expand( \\n\\t )
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$COPY_CMD
```